# error_log file generates 1 GB data text everyday how do I solve this issue

Tags: php, web, error-log

I have some issues with error_log file. Every day its generated 1 GB data file. Daily morning I need to delete this file through FTP login. Because of this large memory sometime I can't access my site. it says internal server error.

How do I solve this error_log file issues.

```
[12-Jul-2014 10:52:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant location_name_zip - assumed 'location_name_zip' in /home/inseedo/public_html/include/template/listing_list_item.php on line 20
[12-Jul-2014 10:52:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant location_name_zip - assumed 'location_name_zip' in /home/inseedo/public_html/include/template/listing_list_item.php on line 20
[12-Jul-2014 10:52:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/inseedo/public_html/include/template/listing_list_item.php on line 37
[12-Jul-2014 10:52:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant location_name_zip - assumed 'location_name_zip' in /home/inseedo/public_html/include/template/listing_list_item.php on line 20
[12-Jul-2014 10:52:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/inseedo/public_html/include/template/listing_list_item.php on line 37
[12-Jul-2014 10:52:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant location_name_zip - assumed 'location_name_zip' in /home/inseedo/public_html/include/template/listing_list_item.php on line 20
[12-Jul-2014 10:52:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant location_name_zip - assumed 'location_name_zip' in /home/inseedo/public_html/include/template/listing_list_item.php on line 20
[12-Jul-2014 10:52:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant location_name_zip - assumed 'location_name_zip' in /home/inseedo/public_html/include/template/listing_list_item.php on line 20
[12-Jul-2014 10:52:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant location_name_zip - assumed 'location_name_zip' in /home/inseedo/public_html/include/template/site_panel_listings.php on line 92
[12-Jul-2014 10:52:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant location_name_zip - assumed 'location_name_zip' in /home/inseedo/public_html/include/template/site_panel_listings.php on line 92
[12-Jul-2014 10:52:10 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant location_name_zip - assumed 'location_name_zip' in /home/inseedo/public_html/include/template/site_panel_listings.php on line 92
```

Comment: Fix the causes. You can search for each error message here on Stack Overflow like [“PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant”](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+Notice%3A+Use+of+undefined+constant) an will certainly find solutions for them.

Comment: No, I’ve a better idea: Send the error log to the developer and tell *him* to fix it.

Comment: It looks like most of the messages are caused by errors on 3 lines. It should take him no time to fix them.

Comment: I have created a `php.ini` text file in that folder and `display_error = 0;`. Now, I don't have a error_log file. Is this good idea to prevent this issue?

Comment: @Beginner - It is better to fix he problem

Answer (score 3):

There're two obvious ways to make a given message stop showing up in the logs:

- Fix the error that's causing it
- Don't log it

The bug itself is fairly straighforward. PHP has several kind of identifiers:

- Variables: `$foo`
- Constants: `foo`
- Strings: `'foo'`

You're possibly using the constant syntax for something that's meant to be a string.

As of logging, you want to change the [`error_reporting` directive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and make it omit `E_NOTICE`. In general, notices should be taken care of in the development server. If they reach production, nobody's going to inspect the log and fix them.

Answer (score -2):

These errors are only notices. If a developer didn't fix them when developing, and you don't want to contact him, simply turn `Off` PHP's `log_errors` directive. Example:

```
#Add this line to .htaccess
php_flag log_errors Off

; or in php.ini find following line and change it
log_errors=Off
```

Comment: I have created a php.ini text file in that folder and display_error = 0;. Now, I don't have a error_log file. Is this good idea to prevent this issue?

Comment: If it solves your problem it is good for you, but `display_errors=0` can slightly make your application slower (if it generates some kinds of errors).
Otherway, try to edit the .htaccess file in your document root adding `php_flag log_errors Off` line to it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does displaying errors speed up an app?

Comment: -1 as you are sugesting to turn off logging completely, as Álvaro G. Vicario suggested, just turn off the logging of notices (E_NOTICE) as it will still log other messages that might be important to know.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario nope,.. it does obviously not ;)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario no, it does not, but turning `display_errors = Off` **slightly** speeds down application - it said Jakub Vrána in his book _1001 tipů a triků pro PHP_.

Comment: @ikkuh I didn't suggest to completely turn off logging, but Beginner said that PHP error.log makes his website inaccessible and wanted to not generate it. I just told him the case, sorry.